# Использую python и BeautifulSoup для парсинга вк. Нужно вытащить имя человека из следующего кода

Tags: python, html, парсер, beautiful-soup

Нужно с помощью BeautifulSoup вытащить имя и фамилию (Саша; Гори-Боль). Я пытался таким образом

```
ProfileName = BSFile.find_all(attrs={"class": "ProfileInfo"})
```

В принципе любым образом получая tag элемента (или как то так в BS это называется) я не могу с помощью .string получить эти слова (получаю я отрезок html-кода). Я просто хочу разобраться с функционалом BS, но в документации я не нашел нужного мне примера. Как мне не используя собственный алгоритм получить эти слова с помощью BS?
Вот отрезок кода, из которого нужно вытащить имя и фамилию

```
<h2 class="OwnerPageName vkuiTitle vkuiTitle--l-2 vkuiTitle--w-1" id="owner_page_name">
Саша
<span class="OwnerPageName__icons">
<span class="OwnerPageName__noWrapText">
Гори-Боль
</span>
<span class="OwnerNameIcon-module__icon--M0gpV" tabindex="-1">
<img class="vkuiIcon" src="https://sun1-19.userapi.com/Tf0zGsL23FVFo-EOwC0cEjxv49R_9IXZghtuhQ/z_GHnNJ8M6I.png" alt="Вас заметили" width="20" height="20">
</span>
</span>
<span class="VisuallyHidden-module__root--h5HaE">&nbsp;заходила 15 минут назад
</span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<h2 class="OwnerPageName vkuiTitle vkuiTitle--l-2 vkuiTitle--w-1" id="owner_page_name">
Саша
<span class="OwnerPageName__icons">
<span class="OwnerPageName__noWrapText">
Гори-Боль
</span>
<span class="OwnerNameIcon-module__icon--M0gpV" tabindex="-1">
<img class="vkuiIcon" src="https://sun1-19.userapi.com/Tf0zGsL23FVFo-EOwC0cEjxv49R_9IXZghtuhQ/z_GHnNJ8M6I.png" alt="Вас заметили" width="20" height="20">
</span>
</span>
<span class="VisuallyHidden-module__root--h5HaE">&nbsp;заходила 15 минут назад
</span>
</h2>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

#1
_, first_name, _, _, last_name, *_ = soup.text.splitlines()
print(first_name, last_name)

#2
first_name, _, last_name, *_ = soup.strings
print(first_name.strip(), last_name.strip())

#3
first_name, last_name, _ = soup.stripped_strings
print(first_name, last_name)
```